# Using a Webform in an MVC3 Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am trying to integrate an old ReportViewer Webform into my current MVC3 project.  I would like it to be available at `http://<server>/Reports/ViewReport.aspx`.  At first I created a folder in the root of my project titled `Reports`, dumped the page in there, and it worked just fine.

However, I now have an Area also called `Reports`, and I had to get rid of the folder in order for the default routing to work correctly.

How can I configure my routing so that the Webform URL appears to be coming from `Reports` even if it's physically elsewhere in my project?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use **IIS URL Rewrite** module. No changes to your application's code or routing. Just place your webpage somewhere in some non-MVC related folder that is also accessible.

http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

But otherwise you could try putting your file directly in area folder as the `RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles` is by default `false` which means that your file *should be* processed by the usual Asp.net web forms pipeline.

The most important thing is though that you don't put your file inside a folder with configured `System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler` handler. By default Views folders have these configured so files within sub-folder tree are inaccessible from request level. Application of course can access them (that's how MVC works anyway).

Comment: Just make sure your URL rule is for `/Reports/ViewReport.aspx` only, if you do it for the entire `/Reports` path, you will break the routing to your Controller.

Comment: @JesseWebb: **Exactly** and thanks for pointing it out because I thought it was self evident.